# How to remove a specific element from an array that is in node.js using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, ejs

I'm trying to put buttons on my page that delete posts the user has made, like on a social network. And I would like to know how I can remove a specific element in my code using js since the array is in node.js. Every time I refresh the page, the element that was deleted using the delete button appears again.

```
<script>
        const deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".ri-close-line");
        const postDelete = document.querySelectorAll(".new-post");
        for(let i = 0; i < postDelete.length; i++) {
            deleteBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                postDelete[i].remove();
            });
        }
    </script>
```

This is the ejs code:

```
<% if (locals.PostArray) { %>
    <% for (let i = 0; i < PostArray.length; i++) { %>
            <% if (locals.createPost) { %>
    <div class="container-new-post">
        <div class="new-post post">
            <div class="image-profile-new-post-box">
                <img src="/images/profile.jpg" alt="Profile image" class="image-profile-new-post">
            </div>
            <div class="text-line-new-post">
                <div class="first-line-new-post">
                    <div>
                        <span class="profile-name-new-post"> XXX </span>
                        <span class="profile-user-new-post"> XXX </span>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="incons-new-post">
                        <i class="ri-pencil-line"></i>
                        <i class="ri-close-line post"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-new-post">
                       <form action="/text" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="text-post" value="<%= PostArray[i] %>" class="text-post-edit" contenteditable="false">
                       </form> 
                </div>
                <div class="last-line-new-post">
                    <div class="incons-new-post" id="incons-new-post1">
                        <i class="ri-chat-3-line"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="incons-new-post" id="incons-new-post2">
                        <i class="ri-repeat-line"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="incons-new-post" id="incons-new-post3">
                        <i class="ri-heart-line"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="incons-new-post" id="incons-new-post4">
                        <i class="ri-bar-chart-grouped-line"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="incons-new-post" id="incons-new-post5">
                        <i class="ri-save-3-line"></i>
                        <i class="ri-share-line"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% } %>    
    <% } %>
    <% } %>
```

And this is my node.js code:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

var userIsAuthorized = false;
var createPostArray = []

let data0;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

function passwordCheck(req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.password === "XXXX" && req.body.email === "XXXX") {
        userIsAuthorized = true;
    }
    next();
}

app.use(passwordCheck);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login.ejs")
});

app.post("/check", (req, res) => {
    if(userIsAuthorized === true) {
        res.redirect("/home");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/");
    }
});

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs", {
        createPost: data0,
        PostArray: createPostArray, 
    })
});

app.post("/post", (req, res) => {
    const textPost = req.body["createPost"];
    data0 = textPost;
    createPostArray.push(textPost);
    res.redirect("/home");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I tried putting the array in js and using the array variable in vanilla js, but that didn't work.

Comment: What array are you referring to? `querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList, not an array.

Comment: The code you posted should remove from the DOM. Can you post a [mre] with plain HTML rather than EJS, so we can run it?

Comment: Every time I refresh the page, the element that was deleted using the delete button appears again. So i need to remove the element [i] from the array "createPostArray"

Comment: You need to use AJAX to send a request to the server to remove it from the DB.